# Boundary Value Problem with Array as Coefficient

Tags: numpy, differential-equations, derivative, equation-solving, boundary

First I am solving a boundary value problem, then I am reusing these results to solve another set of boundary value problems. However that means one of my coefficients in the second set of boundary value problems is an array that mismatches the dimensions when the solver attempts to do this. When I insert the first solver in the function which I pass to the second solver, it still gives me a dimension error. I am unsure how to go around this problem and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
# Define mesh and solution array
x = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, 50)
y = np.zeros((2, x.size))
y2 = np.zeros((4, x.size))
y2[0] = 2.5*x + 1
y2[1] = 3*x 

def fun1(x, y):
# Solve for the Magnetic Field
    B, dB = y;
    d2B = (alpha/(C_k**2*sigma*zeta))*B -U_0*Q*(1/(zeta*C_k))*(1/(np.cosh(Q*x))**2 - 1/(np.cosh(Q/2))**2)
    return dB, d2B

def bc1(ya, yb):
    #Define the boundary of the Magnetic Field
    return ya[0], yb[0]

def func2(x, y2):
    # Call the Magnetic Solver
    sol = solve_bvp(fun1, bc1, x, y)
    B = sol.y[0]
    dB = sol.y[1]
    U = -C_k*zeta*sol.y[1]
    dU = -C_k*zeta*sol.yp[1]

    # define second array
    T, dT, M, dM = y2

    #set out the equations
    d2T = (1/gamma - 1)*(sigma*dU**2 + zeta*alpha*dB**2)#
    d2M =  -(dM/T)*dT + (dM/T)*theta*(m+1) - (alpha/T)*B*dB

    return dT, d2T, dM, d2M

def bc2(ya, yb):
    return ya[0] - 1, yb[0] - 4, ya[2], yb[2] - 1

tempdensity = solve_bvp(func2, bc2, x, y2)
```

Comment: The problem now is that my boundary conditions for U are such that dU = 0 at the boundaries. If I solve all the equations together this means the system is underdetermined. I have went back to my original equations and integrated up for a different approach.
I am trying to solve for U and B at each iteration for T and M because dU and dB will be a fixed length from the first solver and so cannot be matched with the array for T and M at iterations in the next solver as they are fixed.

Comment: I had an idea at solving and then interpolating U and B at each iteration step, but the first solver only gives me access to B and dB as PPoly objects. I need dU to insert into equation for T which means I need d2B which solve_bvp does not give as a PPoly and so cannot be interpolated straight forwardly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the definition of `bc1` change to

```py
sol1 = solve_bvp(fun1, bc1, x, y)
print(sol1.message)

def func2(x, y2):
    # Call the Magnetic Solver
    y = sol1.sol(x)
    yp = fun1(x,y)
    B = y[0]
    dB = y[1]
    U = -C_k*zeta*y[1]
    dU = -C_k*zeta*yp[1]
```

Using the previous constants I get twice a "The algorithm converged to the desired accuracy."